# How to get Julian date Calendar from PHP Date

Tags: php, date

How to get number of jullian date callendar from PHP Date?

example :
i have date variable `$date=date('2018-04-01');`

i want to get value `$jullian_date=????; //return 91`

you can see the table [here](https://landweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/browse/calendar.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`getdate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate) function to get the day of year from a timestamp generated from your date (by [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)):

```php
$info = getdate(strtotime('2018-04-01'));
echo $info['yday'] + 1;    // have to add 1 as PHP numbers days of the year starting at 0
```

Comment: thanks. this is what i expect